# Convert SQL query to equivalent mongodb query

Tags: sql, mongodb-query

I need a help of you guys to convert a SQL query to mongodb query.

This is my query:

```
select *  
from DocumentDetails 
where OldBatchDesc in (select top 1 OldBatchDesc 
                       from DocumentDetails 
                       where DocumentId = '2d0c4fef-21c8-4089-8e48-103055902741')
```

Comment: ok marc thanks. I will take care next time

Answer (score 0):

Indirectly your query wants to get the first entry with DocumentId '2d0c4fef-21c8-4089-8e48-103055902741'

So here's the MongoDB query for the same

```
db.DocumentDetails.find( { DocumentId : '2d0c4fef-8-4089-8e48-103055902741'} ).limit(1)
```

Comment: thanks viswampandya but i was looking for sub query solution. So idea was, i need to get OldBatchDesc from document id and then find all records with that OldBatchDesc. I have achieved it.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Can you share the subquery solution here in the comment box? It will help me to enhance my knowledge for MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

So guys, i have achieved it finally. Putting Solution for future readers. I use Robo3t.

```
db.getCollection('documentdetails').aggregate([
    { "$match": {
        "OldBatchDesc": { 
            "$in": db.getCollection('documentdetails').distinct("OldBatchDesc",{ "DocumentId": "2d0c4fef-21c8-4089-8e48-103055902741" })
        }
    }}
])
```

Comment: Since you only have one stage in your aggregation, you can use `find()` instead.